# Disable opening of popup when downloading a file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress page that allows users to downloads a zip file after 5 secs. In it, I am calling a second page and pass POST parameters ( zip id :: to fetch zip path). The page is called but always as a pop up. I am looking for a **clean download options, where without opening tabs or new window, download begins**. Bypasses popup - blockers also.

I have tried two methods

A) Method 1 ( Jquery Post)

```
$.post(
        "<?php echo get_permalink(get_page_by_title('Download Page')); ?>",
        {attachment_path: "<?php echo $attachment[0]->ID ; ?>"
    }
```

B) Method 2 (Submitting a form)

```
$( '<form action="" method="post" target="_parent" class="hide">
       <input type="hidden" name="attachment_path" value="<?php echo $attachment[0]->ID ; ?>" />
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="target-counter-button"/>
    </form>'
   ).submit();
```

**Edit**

1) Looking for a POST method to implement the logic

2) Due to server restrictions, direct access to *.php files and *.zip files have been blocked

3) Parent Download Page should remain open in the process

Looking for a expert advice on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Just set the header to the correct type and call the URL

Comment: Its a client requirement to first open download page and then start file download after 5 secs

Comment: Just do it without opening a new window then...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by doing a redirect to the path of php script how will output the wanted file with correct HTTP Headers.

**Javascript Part :**

Redirect after 5 second to the 'zipfetcher' script with the zip id

```
<script>
function download(id) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.location = "zipfetcher.php?fileid="+id; // The path of the file to download
    }, 5000); // Wait Time in milli seconds
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="download('123');return false;">Click to download in 5 sec!</a> // Call of the download function when clicked
```

**PHP Part : (aka zipfetcher.php)**

Find the zip path according to zipid then outpout it using [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to the browser with the correct header

```
// Fetch the file path according to $_GET['fileid'] who's been sent by the download javascript function etc.
// ....

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/zip, application/octet-stream'); // Puting the right content type in this case application/zip, application/octet-stream
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filepath));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
readfile($filepath);
exit;
```

Comment: Cannot allow direct link to frontend, its the script job to do it fetch and download it.

Comment: but, I guess we have interactive window here too, that asks to save or to cancel ?? am I rite @isaac

Comment: @RahulGupta I just updated my answer to show you exactly how to do this with the PHP script and the Javascript while hiding the full path, I just tested it on my computer it work like a charm ;)

Comment: @MayurRahul Evertyhing stay on the same page there is no interactive window here

Comment: @Isaac I appreciate your effort, but a popup window opened in chrome(not wanted) will using your code snippet.

Comment: @RahulGupta I changed the javascript and html code can you try it and tell me if it work ? I tried it with chrome and with the change it worked

Comment: @Isaac I  have tried on firefox, chrome, IE. Firefox opens a new tab, while others a new pop up window

Comment: @RahulGupta Is you PHP file outputing anything before the header function is called ? **Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.**